# Unable to retrieve data from Firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Swift iOS app and I'm trying to retrieve data from `Firestore`.

I've set up my `Firestore` database and successfully connected my app to it, but when I try to fetch data from a specific collection I'm not getting any results.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData() {
    db.collection("myCollection").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                // Process the data here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've double-checked my `Firestore collection name` exists and checked the permissions, but the snapshot object still always seems to be nil.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't do anything with the data yet. How did you determine that you're not getting any results?

Comment: Your code is fine, it runs perfectly in my Firestore-based app if I change "myCollection" to a collection that exists. I added a `print(data)` line to see what came back. This makes me think you need to triple check your collection name for typos, make sure you've called `FirebaseApp.configure()` etc.

Comment: By default, you have to be authenticated to read the data - the err would be thrown in that case. It could be  Rules issue, configuration issue or perhaps the code is never called - did you verify it is? A simple way to do that is to add a line of code as the first line within the closure before the `if let` as @jacobdyer mentions to ensure the code is actually called. You can also try adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code and see where it goes off the rails.